# Is exfat-utils missing in debian 12?

Tags: debian, exfat

```
$ apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

returns as output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package exfat-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'exfat-utils' has no installation candidate
```

Tried to install this package but it seems that is missing, is the exfat support made structural inside the kernel already so isn't necessary refer to other utilities to handle this fs ?

do the command for mounting a drive be the same old

```
mount -t exfat /dev/sda1 /mountpoint/
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [Debian 11](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/armhf/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#exfat-in-linux-kernel), exFAT is supported by the kernel. `exfat-utils` has been replaced by `exfatprogs`, you should install the latter instead. `exfat-fuse` is still available should you need it.

To mount an exFAT file system with the kernel driver, use

```
mount -t exfat /path/to/device /path/to/mountpoint
```

as usual; to mount it using the FUSE driver, use

```
mount.exfat-fuse /path/to/device /path/to/mountpoint
```