# Kernel-mounted vs FUSE-mounted exfat filesystem

Tags: linux-kernel, mount, documentation, fuse, exfat

I have read that support for the `exfat` filesystem has been incorporated in the Linux kernel since kernel ver 5.4 was released in late 2019 - early 2020.  I'm confused about what this means wrt the `exfat-fuse` package. AFAIK, the `exfat-fuse` package existed prior to kernel ver 5.4, and was the *ad-hoc* method for mounting `exfat` partitions.

Does incorporation of support for `exfat` filesystems mean that the `exfat-fuse` package is no longer required? Conversely, if `exfat-fuse` is still required, what was meant/accomplished by incorporating `exfat` support in the kernel?

A related question is wrt the documentation for this - specifically `man mount`, and its `FILESYSTEM-SPECIFIC MOUNT OPTIONS` section.  There is no mention of a filesystem-specific  manual for `exfat`, nor is there a "Mount options for exfat" sub-section. Which leads me to ask, *"Where are these mount options for exfat covered?"*  Should users rely upon the "Mount options for fat" sub-section in `man mount`, or should they rely upon `man mount.exfat-fuse`, or on something else?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/759982/70524 and also https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man8/mkfs.exfat.8.html

Comment: @muru: wrt the U&L SE Q&A referenced: I read this during my research, but it doesn't answer my questions. How do you figure it does? wrt the other link for. manpages, I don't get that at all - you've lost me I'm afraid. Care to expound??

Comment: You don't need to use `exfat-fuse` for mounting anymore, now there's just `exfat` (provided by the `mount.exfat` userspace helper from the `exfatprogs` package for the kernel driver). This much is plain from the linked answer. The manpage is for that helper. It describes what's usable with `mount -t exfat`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I linked to the wrong manpage. Looks like (a) no userspace helper is needed at all, a plain `mount -t exfat` works fine without installing anything if the kernel driver is enabled, and (b) looks like it isn't documented much at all. There doesn't seem to be any changes made to `util-linux` (which provides `mount` and its manpage) accompanying this driver.

Comment: Seems like the only readable list of supported options is the [`struct fs_parameter_spec exfat_parameters` object](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.6/fs/exfat/super.c#L227-L249)

Comment: @muru: That code is a reasonable enumeration, but it doesn't help *explain* how the options could be used. Some you can guess, some you know from other man pages, but others...  And wow... 4 years and counting with no documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuse was added on [2005-09-09](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/fs/fuse?id=d8a5ba45457e4a22aa39c939121efd7bb6c76672), that's probably Linux ~2.6.18, far earlier than Linux 5.4

> Does incorporation of support for exfat filesystems mean that the exfat-fuse package is no longer required?

Both can be used but `exfat-fuse` has essentially been deprecated and superseded.

> There is no mention of a filesystem-specific manual for exfat, nor is there a "Mount options for exfat" sub-section.

The man pages are **not** always kept in sync with what the kernel contains. There's a **separate** team maintaining them.

> Should users rely upon the "Mount options for fat" sub-section in man mount, or should they rely upon man mount.exfat-fuse, or on something else?

Mount options for `fuse-exfat` and the kernel native exfat driver are **not** related. They can be similar/the same but that's just happenstance.

You think of these projects as similar/related while they are only similar in name and functionality. Code bases are different and written by different people.

Comment: *"You think of these projects as similar/related while they are only similar in name and functionality."* Yes, I do think of them that way.